# Fortran 77 Real to Int rounding Direction?

Tags: fortran, rounding

Porting a bit of Fortran 77 code.  It appears that REAL variables are being assigned to INTEGER variables.  I do not have a method to run this code and wonder what the behavior is in the following case:

```
REAL*4 A
A = 123.25
B = INT(A)
```

B = 123 or B = 124?

How about at the 0.5 mark?

```
REAL*4 C
C = 123.5
D = INT(C)
```

D = 123 or D = 123.5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`INT`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INT.html) is always rounding *down*:

From the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INT.html):

> These functions return a INTEGER variable or array under the following rules:
>
> (A) If A is of type INTEGER, INT(A) = A
>
> (B) If A is of type REAL and
>   |A| < 1, INT(A) equals 0. If |A| \geq 1, then INT(A) equals the
>   largest integer that does not exceed the range of A and whose sign is
>   the same as the sign of A.
>
> (C) If A is of type COMPLEX, rule B is
>   applied to the real part of A.

If you want to round to the nearest integer, use [`NINT`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NINT.html).

So, in your case `B` and `D` are always `123` (if they are declared as `integer`).

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the link to the docs as well - I'm on the right track through GNU as opposed to college tutorial pages circa 1995.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one example of code and the output, it's an extension of previous answer:

```
PROGRAM test
implicit none
integer               :: i=0
real                  :: dummy = 0.

do i = 0,30
       dummy = -1.0 + (i*0.1)
       write(*,*) i, dummy , int(dummy) , nint(dummy) ,floor(dummy)
enddo
stop
end PROGRAM test
```

This is the output:

```
 $ ./test
      0  -1.000000              -1          -1          -1
      1 -0.9000000               0          -1          -1
      2 -0.8000000               0          -1          -1
      3 -0.7000000               0          -1          -1
      4 -0.6000000               0          -1          -1
      5 -0.5000000               0          -1          -1
      6 -0.4000000               0           0          -1
      7 -0.3000000               0           0          -1
      8 -0.2000000               0           0          -1
      9 -9.9999964E-02           0           0          -1
     10  0.0000000E+00           0           0           0
     11  0.1000000               0           0           0
     12  0.2000000               0           0           0
     13  0.3000001               0           0           0
     14  0.4000000               0           0           0
     15  0.5000000               0           1           0
     16  0.6000000               0           1           0
     17  0.7000000               0           1           0
     18  0.8000001               0           1           0
     19  0.9000000               0           1           0
     20   1.000000               1           1           1
     21   1.100000               1           1           1
     22   1.200000               1           1           1
     23   1.300000               1           1           1
     24   1.400000               1           1           1
     25   1.500000               1           2           1
     26   1.600000               1           2           1
     27   1.700000               1           2           1
     28   1.800000               1           2           1
     29   1.900000               1           2           1
     30   2.000000               2           2           2
```

I hope that this can better clarify the question

EDIT: Compiled with ifort 2013 on xeon

Comment: I think that depends on what you really need, in sense what is the operation to be done and the result to be obtained

Comment: OK, I just wanted to say that assuming int() will always give an expected integer is sometimes dangerous. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/500748

Answer (score 1):

Only as completion to the existing answers I want to add an example how the commercial rounds can be realized without using `NINT` by

```
      L = INT(F + 0.5)
```

where `L` is `INTEGER` and `F` is a positive `REAL` number. I've found this in **FORTRAN 77** code samples from the last century.

Extending this to negative `REAL` numbers by

```
      L = SIGN(1.0,F)*INT(ABS(F) + 0.5)
```

and going back to the 80th of last century, the minimal code example looks like this

```
      PROGRAM ROUNDTEST
      DO 12345 I=0,30
      F = -1.0 + I * 0.1
      J = INT(F)
      K = NINT(F)
      L = SIGN(1.0,F)*INT(ABS(F) + 0.5)
      PRINT *, I, F, J, K, L
12345 CONTINUE
      END
```

which creates the output

```
$ ./ROUNDTEST
           0  -1.00000000              -1          -1          -1
           1 -0.899999976               0          -1          -1
           2 -0.800000012               0          -1          -1
           3 -0.699999988               0          -1          -1
           4 -0.600000024               0          -1          -1
           5 -0.500000000               0          -1          -1
           6 -0.399999976               0           0           0
           7 -0.300000012               0           0           0
           8 -0.199999988               0           0           0
           9  -9.99999642E-02           0           0           0
          10   0.00000000               0           0           0
          11  0.100000024               0           0           0
          12  0.200000048               0           0           0
          13  0.300000072               0           0           0
          14  0.399999976               0           0           0
          15  0.500000000               0           1           1
          16  0.600000024               0           1           1
          17  0.700000048               0           1           1
          18  0.800000072               0           1           1
          19  0.899999976               0           1           1
          20   1.00000000               1           1           1
          21   1.10000014               1           1           1
          22   1.20000005               1           1           1
          23   1.29999995               1           1           1
          24   1.40000010               1           1           1
          25   1.50000000               1           2           2
          26   1.60000014               1           2           2
          27   1.70000005               1           2           2
          28   1.79999995               1           2           2
          29   1.90000010               1           2           2
          30   2.00000000               2           2           2
```

`ROUNDTEST` is compiled and linked by `gfortran` version 7.4.0 by

```
$ gfortran.exe ROUNDTEST.FOR -o ROUNDTEST
```

Hope this helps you if you have to deal with old `FORTRAN` code.